# Onsubmit function not working

Tags: javascript

My onsubmit function is not working.

My PHP file has two forms. Both form tags have an onsubmit attribute that links to the same javascript file. The first form's onsubmit is working. The function being called by the second form has been simplified to this:

```
function UserDataCheck()
{
   return false;
}
```

The form tag is

```
form name='user_form' method='post' onsubmit='return UserDataCheck();'
```

This tag is enclosed within <> and double quotes and echo-ed out in a PHP file.

Please help. This is driving me crazy! Earlier I was doing some data checking in the UserDataCheck() but I stripped all of that away to see if I could even use onsubmit to stop the user from submitting! NO SUCCESS.

Here's more code!

```
 echo "<html>"; 
    echo "<head>"; 
    echo "<title>Survey Form</title>"; 
    echo "<link link rel='stylesheet' href='examples.css' type='text/css'>"; 
    echo "</head>";
echo "<script src='validation.js'></script>"; 
echo "<body topmargin='20', leftmargin='20', rightmargin='20', style='background-color:beige; font-family:calibri;'>"; 
echo "<img src='CSE Global.jpg' width='250' height='70' align='right' />";
//--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
// Firstly, we determine who is using this system 
// Check $_GET['dex'] for a value, if provided, then it's the user 
// if not, then it's the administrator (see my notes below the code for 
// more info) 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------- 

"<input type='text' name='dex' length='50'>";
"<input type='boolean' name='sub' length='1'>";
if ($_GET['dex']=="") {  
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    // $_GET['dex'] is empty so we can presume this is the Admin 
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    echo "<p style='font-family:cambria;font-size:35px;'> WELCOME ADMIN!</p>"; 


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    // We now check to see if the form has been submitted or not ... 
    // To do this, we check if the variable 'sub' is in the $_POST array 
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    if ($_POST['sub']!=1) { 
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        // The form has not been submitted already so present the "admin form" 
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------


// check that they entered an amount tested, an amount passed,
// and that they didn't pass units than they more than tested



        echo "<form name='admin_form' method='post' onsubmit='if(!AdminDataCheck()) return      false;'>"; 
        echo "<p><label>Scope of Service <label style='color:red'><strong>*</strong></label>    <br/></label> <input type='text' name='scope' length='50' id='ScopeofService' onblur='checkScopeofService()'/><label id='labelScopeofService'></label></p>";
```

This is followed by more labels and text fields.

And then the form tag is closed!

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='dex' value={$dex}>"; 
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='sub' value=1>"; 
            echo "<input type='SUBMIT' style='background-color:white' name='submit' value='SUBMIT'>"; 
            echo "</form>";
```

Here's the function in validation.js

```
function AdminDataCheck()
{
var SoS = document.getElementById('ScopeofService').value;
var PNumber = document.getElementById('ProjectNumber').value;
var numericExp = /^[0-9]+$/;
var alphaExp = /^[A-Za-z ]+$/; 
var Email = document.getElementById('Email').value;
var emailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;

if (!(SoS.match(alphaExp)))
{   
alert("Invalid Scope");
return false;
}
else if(!(PNumber.match(numericExp)))
{
alert("Invalid Project Number.");
return false;
}
else if(!(Email.match(emailExp)))
{
alert("Invalid Email.");
return false;
}
else
{
return true;
}
}
```

Let me EMPHASIZE that this was working a few minutes ago and I made no changes, just restarted the browser and the server! And it stopped working. This is really frustrating!

Comment: Can you show the rest? Do you have inline scripts on the submit button

Comment: this has very little to do with php

Comment: please provide some more form html code

Comment: your code totally in mess, are you sure of it, like form must be like `<form name=...etc>` and ended with `</form>` and single quote is missed after `return UserDataCheck();` !

Comment: What is the output in your browser (the source your browser sees, a script's output is not always what you think...) ? When you send the form, any error in the console ?

Comment: @dystroy, **never mind** seems that enter the question before Mohit edit it, it was in mess, now fixed.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have javascript cache problem in your browser ? You may try to import using `<script src='validation.js?v=2'></script>`

Comment: It seems like you might be nesting the form tags, which will cause problems. In the code, you have `"<input type='text' name='dex' length='50'>";`but no echo, and no <form> before it.. perhaps that it a typo, but then you have no </form> before the admin form starts.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
onsubmit='if(!UserDataCheck()) return false;'
```

Comment: My code is not in a mess! form is like that only! And there are no single quotes missing! And of course there is a </form>.

Comment: Ok a minute ago my other submit button was calling a function and doing the data validation using onsubmit and now even thats not working!